# Is this Date class well-written?

Tags: c++, classes, beginner, datetime

I'm a C++ beginner and have made a simple class. But I'm not sure if this is well-written. It's basically just a `Date` class.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Date{
    int d, m, y;    //Day, Month, Year
public:
    Date(int dd = 1, int mm = 1, int yy = 1);

    int addDay(const int &dd) { d += dd; }
    int addMonth(const int &mm) { m += mm; }
    int addYear(const int &yy) { y += yy; }

    int day() const { return d; }
    int month() const { return m; }
    int year() const { return y; }

    void display() const;   //Print to screen

};

void Date::display() const { 
    cout << d << "." << m << "." << y << endl;
}

Date::Date(int dd, int mm, int yy){
    d = dd;
    m = mm;
    y = yy;
}
```

For example, the arguments of `addDay(const int &dd);`. Is that good, or should it just be an integer without `const` and without reference?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For built-in types, there is no point in passing it as a `const&` - prefer a plain `int` (or a `const int`) instead.

Other comments:

1. Your `add-` functions are said to return `int` even though you don't have a `return` statement. I don't think that would or should even compile. Change them to `void`.
2. Take the time to write out `day`, `month` and `year`. The extra seconds in typing is nothing compared to the readability gain.
3. Are you sure you want a default date?
4. Consider [overloading `operator<<` to allow printing your class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading).
5. Consider changing your `display()` function into a `to_string` function instead, and have it return a `std::string`.
6. Make your class easy to use correctly, and hard to use incorrectly. What if `month` is 12 and someone calls `addMonth()`? What is someone passes in June as `month`, but `31` as day? Is `day` day the day of the month, or day of the year? Adhere to the principle of least astonishment. Your class should behave the way users of the class expect it to.
7. Don't pollute the global namespace with `using namespace std`.
8. Split the code into a header and an implementation file. Even though you won't need it now, it's good practice. That makes point 7 even more crucial.

You need to make some judgments to design a `Date` class properly. I won't give you any further suggestions, because it is a good exercise to think about it. Revise your code, and think about the pros and cons of various approaches. Apart from that and the points above, your code looks OK.

Comment: That was fast. :-) I'll try not to repeat anything you've mentioned (if I find anything else).

Comment: @Jamal I was just lucky, I guess :-)

Comment: Indeed.  I managed to answer one question alone yesterday, so that's good enough for me.

Comment: Thank you. To point 3, why shouldn't I use defaults? And to point 5, should i return std::string or const char* ? What do programmers use the most or what would be more efficient ?

Comment: @NormalPeopleScareMe: I'm updating my answer regarding defaults.  As for the other question, `std::string` is preferred in C++.

Comment: I clarified point 5 in the answer. Use `std::string` -- it's more common and more practical to use, and can easily be converted to a C-style string if needed. Regarding defaults: How often do you think users of the class will want a date 2012 years ago?

Comment: The thing is i cannot convert int to string.

Comment: @NormalPeopleScareMe: Yes you can, via `std::stringstream`.  Example: `int num; std::stringstream ss; ss << num; std::string str = ss.str();`

Comment: I do agree with built-in types not being const reference  but you could leave them as const. But that's a whole different discussion :-) (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117293/use-of-const-for-function-parameters)

Comment: @Firedragon Good point, I updated the answer.

Comment: @Firedragon I've been told always to use reference and const when possible. I'll check that topic later. Thank you.

Comment: @NormalPeopleScareMe Always use `const` when possible. Use references when it's the right thing to do. Sometimes you *want* a copy, for example -- then you shouldn't use references. For types that are similar or smaller in size to a pointer, use pass-by-value.

Comment: @Lstor Okay. But in this case where I just need the number of days to add, a reference would be fine. And since I don't change it or I don't want to it's const. Isn't that much more efficient than making a copy ?

Comment: No. When you are passing by reference, you send in the address of the original variable, i.e. you send in a pointer. That means you have to allocate stack space for that pointer and set its value to be the same as the address of the variable. This is pretty much the same as what you would do for an `int`, and the sizes are usually about the same. This means there is no reason to pass a reference. In addition, passing a reference *could* technically cost a bit more.

Answer (score 5):

@Lstor made many great points.  I'll add a few things:

- [About `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).
- Alongside @Lstor's point regarding writing out your data members, I would recommend initializing them on separate lines.  Also, when you do rename your members as such, your accessors should be renamed as well.  Otherwise, they will end up having the same name, which will cause errors.
- Pet-peeve here: using `int` when dealing with only positives.  I would prefer `unsigned int` instead.  You could even `typedef` them, but that's up to you.
- Your constructor should have an initializer list instead.  So, this:

  ```
  Date::Date(int dd, int mm, int yy){
      d = dd;
      m = mm;
      y = yy;
  }
  ```

  would look like this:

  ```
  Date::Date(int dd, int mm, int yy) : d(dd), m(mm), y(yy) {}
  ```
- If you still want a default date, you would need a default constructor as well.  The one above allows the user to set his/her own date.  This one also has an initializer list, but without arguments:

  ```
  // the year can default to anything, but I chose 2000 for my example
  Date::Date() : d(1), m(1), y(2000) {}
  ```

Comment: So the default constructor would be the constructor from your example which I'll add to the existing one?

Comment: @NormalPeopleScareMe: yes, an additional one.  You can have multiple constructors as long as their arguments (or lack of arguments) vary.

Comment: You can have a constructor with default arguments *and* an initializer list, too. `Date::Date(int d = 1) : day(d)`.

Comment: @Lstor: Right.  Is that preferred over what I mentioned, or does it not matter?

Comment: It depends. When you have a default value that makes sense, use defaults. If you don't, you should probably just do plain overloading, or maybe only keep the version that takes arguments. In any case, don't use overloading to simulate defaults, and vice versa. Java opted to drop default arguments altogether, whereas for example C# and Python also have them. Item 24 of *Effective C++* (2nd Ed.) discusses the issue further.

Comment: @Lstor: Ah, okay.  I haven't even finished reading the first edition.

Comment: I mean *Effective C++*, not *More Effective C++*. It's been made in three versions/editions. I got the second edition when I bought my copy 13 years ago, so surely you have either the second or third? :-) The third edition came out in 2005. However, it seems that the relevant item is not included in the third edition.

Comment: @Lstor: Okay, that makes more sense.  I have _Effective C++_, 3rd edition.  I haven't had time yet to finish it, but I will.

Comment: `Same thing, but a different format and is preferred.` is misleading. An initializer list and the constructor content are not the same thing. Elements are initialized (either explicitly, or implicitly if they're not in the list) and then the constructor is run.

Comment: @Corbin: You're right.  I was just thinking about the contents in general.  I'll change it.

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in bugs/missing functionality in addition to design issues, your `addDay()`, etc methods need to handle overflows.  ex

```
Date foo = new Date(10, 7, 2013);
foo.addDay(30); //currently sets foo to July 40th, 2013.

Date bar = new Date(10, 7, 2013);
bar.addDay(-30); //currently sets bar to July -20th, 2013.
```